How to Encourage Users to Submit Multiple Price Requests on Our App?
Our app allows users to ask the price from vendors. The flow is as follows:

Click on the 'Request price' button
Fill and submit a form

The information filled in the form is saved and can be reused to resubmit the form for other vendors.
We have noticed that users don't send more than one request because they assume that they have to refill the form every time.
Do you have any suggestions on how to mitigate this issue?
We tried displaying a popup at the end of the flow that says "Your information is saved for next uses"


What happens when they press request price? Can you show us the end-to-end flow?

Have you noticed users don't send more than one request because they assume they'll have to refill the form every time? Or are you assuming that's why users don't request multiple prices?
Could the pop-up at the end of the flow suggest other vendors and clearly offer one-click request price actions to quote with those vendors? That would be my recommendation with the info I have.
If you can share your flows or more screens from your app, I would happily dive in a make better, more informed recommendations :)
